# Doctrine: complicated select with two ManyToMany relationships

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I need to query a number of issues in a table of a issue tracking system limiting this query by a complicated condition:

Issues (Entity) are grouped into categories (another Entity). Persons (Entity) are members of multiple roles (fourth Entity), this is one ManyToMany relationship. And finally, a role can have access on one or many categories, this is the second ManyToMany relationship.

```
<?php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="issue")
 */
class Issue
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", fetch="EAGER")
     * @JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="RESTRICT", nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;
    …
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $roles;
    …
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="role")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $persons;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="roles")
     * @JoinTable(name="role_has_access_on_category",
     *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $categories;
    …
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="person")
 */
class Person
{   
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="persons")
     * @JoinTable(name="person_is_member_of_role",
     *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $roles;
    …
}
```

I have left all fields except the relationship ones away, of course there are primary keys and a lot more columns there…

I want to retrieve all issues that belong to categories to which a person with a given primary key has access via the roles it is member of.

At first I just started to experiment how to query ManyToMany relationships, so the code below does not really resemble my target.
I have finally found out how I can get the query to retrieve the other side of one ManyToMany relationship, so I can already get the roles a person belongs to. But this query does not fetch the categories a role has access to.

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('person')
   ->addSelect('role')
   ->addSelect('category')
   ->from('Person', 'person')
   ->innerJoin('person.roles', 'role')
   ->innerJoin('role.categories', 'category');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

$result contains the persons data with all associated roles, but a blank array of categories instead of the entities. The final query would start from the issue side of course, but for now I would only like to get through to the other side…

So now I wonder whether I have to take all the roles and loop through them to fetch all categories. Is there no easier Doctrine way?

By the way, that's the SQL I would use:

```
SELECT issue.* FROM person AS p, person_is_member_of_role AS pim, role_has_access_on_category AS rha, issue
WHERE
    p.id = pim.person_id AND
    pim.role_id = rha.role_id AND
    rha.category_id = todo.category AND
    p.id = ?;
```

I hope this all makes it clear somehow, otherwise I will revise my question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating it by trying to put all join conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

If I understood the question correctly, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    i
FROM
    Issue i
JOIN
    i.category c
JOIN
    c.roles r
JOIN
    r.persons p
WHERE
    p.id = :personId
```

Translated in `QueryBuilder` API:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$issues = $qb
    ->select('i')
    ->from('Issue', 'i')
    ->innerJoin('i.category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.roles', 'r')
    ->innerJoin('r.persons', 'p')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.id', ':personId'))
    ->setParameter('personId', $personId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Also, consider avoiding the `QueryBuilder` if there's no good reason to use it. After all, it's just a string builder.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Especially the `expr()` part is interesting!
You say I should avoid the `QueryBuilder`, but is this possible in this scenario? I use the regular `findByX` methods where I can already.

Comment: The query builder just assembles a string (you can check the method `getQuery` of `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder` if you're interested in its implementation). You can just use `$em->createQuery($someDql)` in most cases. The Query Builder becomes very useful only when you have a dynamically assembled query

Comment: Thanks! I will try to go over the controllers again and find places where I can change that.